# Regex Exclude Character From Group

Tags: regex

I have a response:

```
MS1:111980613994
124 MS2:222980613994124
```

I have the following regex:

```
MS\d:(\d(?:\r?\n?)){15}
```

According to Regex, the "`(?:\r?\n?)`" part should let it match for the group but exclude it from the capture (so I get a contiguous value from the group).

Problem is that for "`MS1:xxx`" it matches the `[CR][LF]` and includes it in the group.  It should be excluded from the capture ...

Help please.

Comment: You should indicate what implementation of regex matching you're using (e.g., Perl, PCRE, PHP, JavaScript, .Net, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

The `(?:...)` syntax does **not** mean that the enclosed pattern will be excluded from any capture groups that enclose the `(?:...)`.

It only means that that the group formed by `(?:...)` will be a non-capturing group, as opposed to a new capture group.

Put another way:

- `(?:...)` only **groups**
- `(...)` has two functions: it both **groups** and **captures**.

Capture groups capture *all* of the text matched by the pattern they enclose, **even the parts that are matched by nested groups** (whether they are capturing or not).

#### An example

With the regex...

```
.*(l.*(o.*o).*l).*
```

...there are two capture groups. If we match this against `hello world` we get the following captures:

- 1: `lo worl`
- 2: `o wo`

Note that the text captured by group 2 is also captured by group 1.

If we change the inner group to be non-capturing...

```
.*(l.*(?:o.*o).*l).*
```

...group 1's capture will not be changed (when matched against the same string), but there is no longer a group 2:

- 1: `lo worl`

As you can see, if a non-capturing group is enclosed by a capture group, that enclosing capture group *will* capture the characters matched by the non-capturing group.

#### What are they For?

The purpose of non-capturing groups is not to exclude content from other capturing groups, but rather to act as a way to group operations without also capturing.

For example, if you want to repeat a substring, you might write `(?:substring)*`.

#### How do I solve my real problem?

If you really want to ignore embedded `\r`s and `\n`s your best bet is to strip them out in a second step. You don't say what language you're using, but something equivalent to this (Python) should work:

```
s = re.sub(r'[\r\n]', '', s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you mean to do here is place the [CR][LF] matching part outside of the captured group, something like: `MS\d:(\d){15}(?:\r?\n?)`

Comment: Unless there can be newlines scattered through the 15 digits.  Also, you really don't need grouping on the newlines in that case.

Answer (score 0):

So far as I know, you'll have to use 2 regexes. One is "MS\d:(\d(?:\r?\n?)){15}", the other is used to remove the line breaks from the matches.

Please refer to "[Regular expression to skip character in capture group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277547/regular-expression-to-skip-character-in-capture-group)".

Answer (score -2):

How about `MS\d:(?:(\d)\r?\n?){15}`

Comment: Unmatched parens in the pattern, FYI.