# Get data from receipt using regular expressions

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, split

I am using regular expressions to get each line item's data from a receipt.
The receipts are going to look like this:

```
Qty Desc
1   JD *#
    MARTINI *#   
2   XXXXXX 
3   YYYYYY
4   JD
    PEPSI *#
```

All items have quantities and descriptions, and some of them have an extra `*#`. Also, note that the descriptions can have spaces in them, **and even more than one line, each line being able to have its own** `*#`. I want to catch the quantity and description (if more than one line, get all lines), and I do not care at all about the extra `*#`. So in this example, for the first line item I would catch Quantity=1 and Description="JD MARTINI". For the fourth, Quantity=4 and Description="JD PEPSI".

My current regular expression looks like this:

```
((\d+)\s+(.*)(\s+\*#)?)
```

It is not working, and I assume it is because making the last parenthesis optional allows the greedy `(.*)` to catch absolutely everything. If the last parenthesis wasn't optional, the regular expression would do its job for the line items with the extra `*#`, but it wouldn't match the first and third one (because they don't have the extra `*#`).

Any ideas?

Comment: Are your descriptions all solid text, or do they have spaces in them?

Comment: @Ann L - good job, I was just going to ask that :-)

Comment: You might want to try the regex test harness at regexlib.com, BTW.  I've found it very helpful.

Comment: Sorry for forgetting to mention that. They do have spaces in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your modified question, I have determined that what you wish to accomplish cannot be done with one regular expression.  You will have to do a combination of regex match + replace. (see this question: [Regular expression to skip character in capture group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277547/regular-expression-to-skip-character-in-capture-group))

Match Regex: (\d+)\s+([A-Z\s*#]*[A-Z]+)

Replace Regex: (*#(\s*))|(\r\n\s+)(?=\s)

The match regex will match the quantity and the item description, including any in-between line breaks or *# occurrences, leaving out the final *#.  I am assuming the last character in a description is a letter.

After you run the match regex, you will get an array of matches back out, which you will need to iterate through to turn into objects.  I wrote some handy code to do that for you.  For each object, you will run the replace regex on the object's description, which will remove the extraneous spaces and *#.

```
     class ReceiptItem
    {
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0}\t{1}", Quantity, Description);
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var matches = Regex.Matches(textBox1.Text, @"(\d+)\s+([A-Z\s\*\#]*[A-Z]+)", RegexOptions.Multiline);
        var items = (from Match m in matches
                     select new ReceiptItem()
                                {
                                    Quantity = int.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value),
                                    Description = Regex.Replace(m.Groups[2].Value, @"(\*\#(\s*))|(\r\n\s+)(?=\s)", "")
                                });

        listBox1.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray());
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't do exactly what I need, but it's my fault for not giving a better and more explained example of what I'm trying to accomplish. Please take a look at the edited question.

Comment: Great job and perfectly explained. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex (with `Multiline` option):

```
(\d+)\s+(?:(.*)(?:\s+\*#)|([^#]*))$
```

Comment: It may be because I'm using The Regex Coach, but it doesn't match anything.

Comment: I tried it on this page: http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Comment: It's matching in Regex Coach. Have you checked the multiline box?

Comment: If you use this as target string: "1 Example One\n\n1 Example Two *#\n   Test 1 *#\n1 Example Three *#\nTest 2 *#", it will not match "1 Example Two *#", and it will capture a few extra spaces with "1 Example One".

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.  I think it does what you need.

```
((\d+)\s+(.+?)(\s+\*#)*)
```

Comment: It only gets the first character of each line item's description.