# Using regex to remove text between two parts of a string

Tags: java, regex

I need to match certain parts of a string using regex and am having a terrible time trying to figure it out.  The string in question will always look like this:

```
CN=Last.First.M.1234567890, OU=OrganizationalUnit, O=Organization, C=CountryName
```

The resulting string will look like `CN=1234567890,` so I need to just get the first part of the string up to and including the `,` and strip out the `Last.First.M.` part.  Can this be done?

Note: I am passing this regex into a function which I cannot touch, so I cannot use easier methods such as splitting the string or getting just the digits and adding the `CN=` to it.

Thanks.

Comment: What language or tool are you using?

Comment: What parameters does this function take exactly, and what does it return?

Comment: @squiguy I am using java

Comment: @TimPietzcker The function takes a `String` value and returns a `Pattern` from the `java.util.regex.Pattern` class.

Comment: What do you mean by that it will always look like that? I'm guessing that you mean that it will always be of the form 'CN=***, OU=***, O=***, C=***', but that the *** can be any other text?

Comment: Oh, so it just compiles the regex you pass to it into a `Pattern` object? I don't get it - what do you need this function for? What can you do with that object?

Comment: Creating the regex for this is simple, but I agree that we need details on how that `Pattern` object that's returned will be used. Do you have control over the code that calls this particular method?

Comment: @steinar For the most part, yes.  The CN form will always be Last.First.M.10digitcode, the rest is irrelevant.  The `Pattern` object will be passed to an extractor class.
@TimPietzcker I need it for an extractor class, more specifically an x509 principal extractor

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Regular expression to skip character in capture group](http://stackoverflow.com/q/277547/299327)

Answer (score 1):

Here's something I do when I'm to lazy to play around with regex.

```
String[] myStrings = "CN=Last.First.M.1234567890, OU=OrganizationalUnit, O=Organization, C=CountryName"
    .split(",");
// myStrings [0] now contains CN=Last.First.M.1234567890

myStrings[0] = myStrings[0].replace("Last.First.M.", "");
// now we replaced the stuff we didnt want with nothing and myStrings[0]
// is looking pretty nice. This is a lot more readable but probably
// performs worse. For even more readable code assign to variables rather then to modify myStrings[0]
```

Comment: Sorry missed the part that you couldn't cheat. Other answers are better for you!

Answer (score 1):

I believe I found the answer to what I am looking for here after doing more digging.

[Regular expression to skip character in capture group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277547/regular-expression-to-skip-character-in-capture-group)

All answers here were great, just didn't apply to what I was working on.  Now I will work on a different method to solve this.  Thanks for all the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

With the regexp `([A-Z]{2})=(?:\w+\.)+(\d+),` you can obtain the parts that you want.

Comment: This matches the whole `CN=Last.First.M.1234567890,` rather than just selecting `CN=1234567890,` when I tried it using http://regexr.com?33mcn

Comment: it captures two groups: `CN` and `123456789`. Then one should just use a variation of @aleroot solution like `m.group(1) + "=" + m.group(2)`

Comment: The OP stated that `I am passing this regex into a function which I cannot touch, so I cannot use easier methods such as splitting the string or getting just the digits and adding the CN= to it.` So I believe concatenating the groups won't work for this.