# Non-capture group inside a named capture group

Tags: regex

I am trying to match a non-capture group inside a named capture group in a .NET regular expression, but for some reason the non-capture group is still being captured:

- input: "A/B"
- actual output: Token = "A/B"
- desired output: Token = "AB"

my attempt using a non-capture group:

```
(?<Token>\w(?:/)\w)
```

I've got a feeling that I need to use a lookahead and/or a lookbehind here, but I still can't get it working. Any ideas?

Comment: `(?:/)` is equivalent to just `/`.

Comment: Can you use a replace instead of a match and store the result of the replace in a variable?

Comment: No unfortunately not. Further searching on SO led me to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277547/regular-expression-to-skip-character-in-capture-group) question, so I guess it's just not possible

Comment: Can you do a regexp replace on the string before extracting the token?

Answer (score 2):

The `(?:/)` part is still contained within the capture group, it just doesn't form its own capture group.  You could do:

```
(\w)(?:/)(\w)
```

This will capture the `A` and `B` in *separate* capture groups, but that doesn't do exactly what you want.

What you can do is capture the entire group `(?<Token>\w/\w)` and then do a string replace of `/` with nothing.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I unfortunately can't perform any post processing on the regex's match result. I need to extract the final token using a single expression

Comment: @Adriaan I'm afraid you're stuck since regexen simply don't work that way.  Can you do a regex replace?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
1.9.3-p545 :022 > line = "A/B"
 => "A/B" 
1.9.3-p545 :023 > test = line.scan(/([A-z: ]+)/).flatten.join()
 => "AB" 
1.9.3-p545 :024 >
```