# Exclude a slash in capture group of regex

Tags: regex

i have string, which has the value like

```
"urls":[
        {
         "url":"https:\/\/t.co\/OjiDUThEvK",
         "expanded_url":"http:(escape sequence slash)/(escape sequence slash)/fb.me\/7Wnh0hMLL",
         "display_url":"fb.me(escape sequence slash)/7Wnh0hMLL",
         "indices":[48,71]}],
         "user_mentions":[],
         "symbols":[]
        }
      ]
```

i need to capture only "expanded url" i tried the following regex:

```
"expanded_url"\:\"http\:\\\/\\\/(.*?)\"
```

this gave a result :

```
"fb.me(escape sequence slash)/7Wnh0hMLL"
```

but i want to exclude the escape sequence slash in the URL, is it possible to achieve the same, kindly let me know the changes to me made to the regex

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.  Why don't you deserialize your json to get the url?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if this is what you're after. Can you post the raw input without the "(escape sequence slash)" part I'm assuming that this is actually / in the text you're matching against.

match:

```
\"expanded_url\":\"http:\\\/\\\/([^\\]*)\\\/([^\\"]*)\"
```

replace with:

```
$1/$2
```

Comment: Your assumption is correct, i am not able to put / since stack over flow is ignoring it. The above regex give two match groups 
1. fb.me
2. 4sQlKWaQZ but i am expecting only one capture group with output  fb.me/4sQlKWaQZ

Comment: There isn't a way to ignore the `\ ` from the `\/ ` in the middle of the group. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277547/regular-expression-to-skip-character-in-capture-group  Basically you will need to have 2 groups and concatenate them later.