# Get value from brackets by regular expression (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I have two variants of string:

```
Key ("vinCode")=(V1234567890123456) some text.
Key (vinCode)=(V1234567890123456) some text.
```

I'm trying to get values from brackets (vinCode, V1234567890123456).
Currently I have such regular expression:

```
(?<=\().*?(?=\))
```

But it gets values with `""`, e.g ("vinCode", vinCode, V1234567890123456).

Is it possible to create expression which can get values always without `""`?

Comment: Your answer is in the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/277565/16857762

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an optional match of `"` in the look-behind part, and then require that the next character is not an `"`. The closing quote can be matched with a back-reference to the captured first quote:

```js
let regex = /(?<=\((")?)(?!").*?(?=\1\))/g;

let tests = [
   'Key ("vinCode")=(V1234567890123456) some text.',
   'Key (vinCode)=(V1234567890123456) some text.'
];

for (let test of tests) {
    console.log(test.match(regex));
}
```

Note: this regex will not match an empty string in quotes: `("")`

Comment: I would just do `[^"]*?` instead of `(?!").*?`