# Regex: Extract digits separated by a hyphen

Tags: regex

What I have:  `123456789-987654321`
What I need:  `3456789-4321`  (keep last 7 digits from 1st group and keep last 4 digits from 2nd group)

```
(\d{7})-         gets me 3456789-
((\d{4})$(?<=))  gets me 4321
```

I can't figure out how to combine the 2 to get what I need.

Comment: This question should be closed due to the premises of having one match with skipped elements inside. Check it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277547/regular-expression-to-skip-character-in-capture-group.

Answer (score 0):

You can match optional digits and then capture the 7 digits and the hyphen. Then match again optional digits and capture the last 4.

In the replacement use the 2 capture groups.

```
^\d*(\d{7}-)\d*(\d{4})$
```

Comment: Thanks but I am limited to one expression in my system.

Comment: @JenL You can not skip characters for a single match. You could try using an alternation, but that will still give you 2 matches `\d{7}-|\d{4}$` https://regex101.com/r/7f2OPV/1 What is your "system"?

Comment: System is BlackLine.

Comment: @JenL Is there some online documentation available related to the product using a regex?