# Regex - Query for Efficient and shorter way to Match but skip an optional character (Space) in a capture group output

Tags: regex

I have recently learnt about capturing groups and non capturing groups. I need to match but skip from output a single space character from text.

After 3 Tries, I got the hint from below Stack Overflow post and revised my understanding and got the problem solved.
[Regular expression to skip character in capture group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277547/regular-expression-to-skip-character-in-capture-group)

All I want is to know if there is any other method which is more efficient / shorter than what I did.

--Data Start--

TRA-1728 (CS-02)
Medium Taupe / White

Be Here Now

TRA-1723(CS-02)
White Ice / Charcoal Slate

--Data End--

--Existing Code Start--
([A-Z]{2,}-\d+ ?(?:([^)]+))?)\s?(?:\n)?([A-Za-z\s]+)/\s+([^\n]+)
--Existing Code End--

--Existing Output Details Start--

Match 1:
TRA-1728 (CS-02)
Medium Taupe / White

Group1:
TRA-1728 (CS-02)

Group2:
Medium Taupe

Group3:
White

Match 2:
TRA-1723(CS-02)
White Ice / Charcoal Slate

Group1:
TRA-1723(CS-02)

Group2:
White Ice

Group3:
Charcoal Slate

--Existing Output Details End--

--Problem Statement Start--
Am able to match if the space is there with below code but am not able to remove it (i.e. the single space) from output.

([A-Z]{2,}-\d+(?: )?\ ?(?:([^)]+))?)\s?(?:\n)?([A-Za-z\s]+)/\s+([^\n]+)

In Above "Existing Output Details" Match 2 is Fine but Group 1 of Match 1 carries the space which needs to be excluded

I also tried below code but it appears that my understanding of non capturing groups is still lacking

([A-Z]{2,}-\d+(?: )?(?:([^)]+))?)\s?(?:\n)?([A-Za-z\s]+)/\s+([^\n]+)

**Finally Below Code gets it done but now the number of groups rises to 5

(([A-Z]{2,}-\d+) ?((?:([^)]+))?)\s?)(?:\n)?([A-Za-z\s]+)/\s+([^\n]+)

I am simply asking if there is any simple / short way of doing this?**

--Problem Statement End--

--Desired Output Details Start--

Match 1:
TRA-1728(CS-02)
Medium Taupe / White

Group1:
TRA-1728(CS-02)

Group2:
Medium Taupe

Group3:
White

Match 2:
TRA-1723(CS-02)
White Ice / Charcoal Slate

Group1:
TRA-1723(CS-02)

Group2:
White Ice

Group3:
Charcoal Slate

--Desired Output Details End--

Comment: Shortness of the pattern mainly depends on how accurate you need it to be. Maybe it will suffice if you use something like [this variant](https://regex101.com/r/i0o9mh/1). Only you know what different data can possibly appear.

Comment: *Sidenote*: Formatting of the question is a bit hard to read (at least to me). Have a look at [How do I format my code blocks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). Also "output" and "desired output" look so similar, that it's a challenge to discover the differences without reading description or title. Less can be more sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your time and valuable suggestion.

I have come to think that asking community for such tasks using so many man hours (of everyone) just for curiosity is not a good thing to do.

I close this question of mine with the answer as below.

"Use sub capturing groups inside a capturing group"

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is optionally repeat the character class containing the `\s` followed by the character class without it.

Changing  `([A-Za-z\s]+)\/` ---> `([A-Za-z\s]*[a-zA-Z])\s*\/`

The adjusted pattern would be:

```
([A-Z]{2,}-\d+ ?(?:\([^)]+\))?)\s?\n?([A-Za-z\s]*[a-zA-Z])\s*\/\s+(.+)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pbwRWG/1).

**Note** that `(?:\n)?` can be shortened to `\n?` and the backslash needs no escaping unless the delimiters are also `/`

Answer (score 0):

> *"... All I want is to know if there is any other method which is more efficient / shorter than what I did. ...*

Here is a simplified pattern.

```
(?:([A-Z]{2,}-\d+ ?\(.+?\))\s*)?(.+) / (.+)
```

```
TRA-1728 (CS-02), Medium Taupe, White
TRA-1723(CS-02), White Ice, Charcoal Slate
```